# Exercise 1.5.7 (c) in Grimmett and Stirzaker

Tags: probability

Jane has three children, each of which is equally likely to be  a boy or a girl independently of the others. Define the events:

$$A = \{\text{all the children are of the same sex}\},$$
$$B = \{\text{there is at most one boy}\}.$$ 
$$C = \{\text{the family includes a boy and a girl}\}.$$

(a) Show that $A$ is independent of $B$, and that $B$ is independent of $C$

(b) Is $A$ independent of $C$?

(c) Do these results hold if boys and girls are not equally likely?

We can see that $A = \{BBB, GGG\}$, $B = \{BGG, GBG, GGB, GGG\}$, and $C= \{BGG, GBG, GGB, BBG, BGB, GBB\}$. Thus, considering that there are total 8 combinations of girls and boys, (a) and (b) can be easily shown.

But, I am not sure how to solve (c). I don't even know where I use the assumption that boys and girls are equally likely when solving (a) and (b).

The solution for (c) is that "only in the trivial cases when children are either almost surely boys or almost surely girls." Does this mean that (a) and (b) holds only if Jane has either all three boys or all three girls? Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: So how did you show the results in (a) and (b)? Did you ever use the result that the probability of a particular child being a boy is $1/2$? If yes, then you already assume that boys and girls are equally likely. The solution refer to the fact that if there is a trivial event $E$, i.e. $P(E) = 0$ or $P(E) = 1$, then $E$ will be independent to any other event, including $E$ itself. This is well known and can be easily proven. So in your case, by simple calculation with the definition of independence, you can simply conclude that $B$ is trivial or $A$ and $C$ are trivial. And that conclude.

Comment: For (a), I need to show that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$, and I know that $P(A \cap B) = P(\{GGG\}) = 1/8$, and $P(A) = P(\{ BBB, GGG\}) = 1/4$, and similarly $P(B) = 1/2$. So, I did not use 1/2, did I?

Comment: So how did you come up with $P(\{GGG\}) = 1/8$?

Comment: because there are total 8 combinations of girls and boys

Comment: So you are saying that each combination are equally likely, or equivalently a particular child has a particular sex have a probability of $1/2$ as it consist of $4$ combinations.

Comment: umm... then how can I answer when each combination is not equally likely?